# How to get DocuSign Bearer Token

Tags: token, docusignapi

I want to use these APIs from backend:
https://apiexplorer.docusign.com/#/esign/restapi?categories=Authentication&tags=Authentication&operations=login&mode=basic

The problem is from where I can get the bearer token in Backend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DocuSign /RESTAPI/v{2, 2.1}/ login, updatePassword, revokeOAuthToken, getOAuthToken API methods are obsolete and should not be used for any application.

Instead, use the DocuSign OAuth2 flows to obtain Bearer tokens:

- [Authorization Code Grant](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/authentication/oauth2-code-grant)
- [JWT Grant](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/authentication/oauth2-jsonwebtoken)
- [Implicit Grant](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/authentication/oauth2-implicit)

Recommendation: use libraries for the OAuth flows. See the `eg-01-*-jwt` example repos for the JWT Grant flow and the `eg-03-*-auth-code-grant` example repos for Authorization Code Grant. The example repos are on https://github.com/docusign

The examples are also discussed on developers.docusign.com